# Add the code numbers on the back of the url?

Tags: php, apache

How to add code number back this url:
http://tiwar.net/user/123/
The `/123/` is code number and not folder 
/user/ is folder that contains `index.php`
But when i add number `/123/` i got error page..how to create this url?

Comment: You should strt reading about "URL rewriting" and your http servers "rewrite module" for this. It is well documented and endless examples exist for this.

Comment: use .htaccess for url rewrite

Comment: @Farhan Usage of `.htaccess` style files should only be considered if no other options exist. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and _really_ slow the server down. If possible it is always the better approach to place such commands in the server configuration.

Comment: @arkascha is there other way other than .htaccess

Comment: @Farhan Sure there is. Actually I explained that in the comment above. It is very well documented.

Comment: @arkascha can you tell me the code for rewrite .htaccess?

Comment: @RioSusanto As mentioned there are millions of examples that _have_ already been written. All of those, which you can easily find yourself, do not help? _Why not?_ Please note that this place is _not_ a free coding service. You are expected to code yourself. We are only here to offer advice and help. We are not here to do your work for you.

Comment: @arkascha ok, thanks for the advice and your help

Comment: @RioSusanto If you implemented the rewriting yourself and somehow fail to get it to work, _then_ is the time to come here, post your code and tell what is wrong with that, why you think you have an issue. But I am certain that you will succeed yourself when looking at a few examples.

Comment: @arkascha yeah I guess maybe I just experiencing a bit of a problem

Comment: @arkascha I do not find the reference, why don't you tell me, please? :'(

Comment: You mean the reference to the documentation? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try with this one as a start:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/user/([0-9]+)/?$ /user/index.php?code=$1
```

Obviously the rewriting module must be installed and activated for this to work.

Note that this is the variant for the http server configuration. For usage in `.htaccess` style files you have to remove the trailing slash (`/`) from the rule pattern. But you should only fall back to such files if you really have no access to the server configuration. Those files are kind of a last resort. They are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and *really* slow the server down.

This is the documentation for [apache's rewriting module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). It is of excellent quality and comes with really good examples.

Comment: Sure, you are welcome. Now do yourself a favor and work to understand _how_ that works. Take a good look into the documentation. That is the only way to really learn instead of just doing copy&paste :-)